# Can not read the property of `bind` ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I get an error. I find many solution but not so help full. What is solution of this and please explain it little bit because I am the beginner in React and Redux.

> Leads.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

```
import { getLeads, deleteLead } from "../../actions/leads";
```

```js
<button 
onClick={this.props.deleteLead.bind(this, lead.id)} 
className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
   Delete
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are binding this method here?

**The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.****

To know more about bind, here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Try like this, it should works:

```
onClick={deleteLead(lead.id)}
```

Comment: Now it gives this error   `Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.deleteLead is not a function`

Comment: Can you please show me your deleteLead method?

Comment: This is deleteLead Method  `// DELETE Lead
export const deleteLead = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .delete(`/api/leads/${id}/`)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_LEAD,
        payload: id,
      });
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};`

Comment: This new code is working but it delete from database but not remove from UI.

Comment: @WaleedurRehman You have to hide it as soon as you get delete response from api.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { getLeads, deleteLead } from "../../actions/leads";
```

you have to not use this.props.
with this is enought

```
<button 
onClick={deleteLead( lead.id)} 
className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
   Delete
</button>
```

Comment: This code is working but it deletes from the database but not remove from UI. And I want it to remove from UI also.